# Getting most sold products complex sql

Tags: mysql, sql

TABLE STRUCTURES:

**Orders** OrderID, OrderStatusID, ......
**OrderDetails** ODID,ODProductID, ODProductQty, ODOrderID
**Products** ProductID, ProductName...

MY SQL so far:

```
SELECT * FROM Products 
INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ODProductID 
INNER JOIN Orders ON OrderDetails.ODOrderID = Orders.OrderID 
where Orders.OrderStatusID = '5'
```

OrderStatusID must be 5 (For Delivered Order).

I just want result to be ProductName & NoOfProducts of most sold product.

Can be like top 4 products sold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must group by product and aggregate.
Then sort the results descending for the number of products sold and limit the results to 4 products:

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.ProductName, COUNT(DISTINCT d.ODID) NoOfProducts 
FROM Products p 
INNER JOIN OrderDetails d ON p.ProductID = d.ODProductID 
INNER JOIN Orders o ON d.ODOrderID = o.OrderID 
WHERE o.OrderStatusID = '5'
GROUP BY p.ProductID, p.ProductName
ORDER BY NoOfProducts DESC
LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Wel your code works But i had used this:

Anything wrong with my code:

```SELECT Products.ProductName, Products.ProductCode, COUNT(Products.ProductID) as MostProducts FROM Products INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ODProductID INNER JOIN Orders ON OrderDetails.ODOrderID = Orders.OrderID where Orders.OrderStatusID = '5' GROUP BY Products.ProductID ORDER BY MostProducts DESC  LIMIT 5```

Comment: I got same results as your's for first 3. not 5. any idea where i went wrong here? Or my approach was wrong?

Comment: Ok i think its cause other record got same no of values. Nevermind.

Comment: LIMIT will not return rows with ties. If there are products with the same NoOfProducts in the last place they will be left out.

Answer (score 0):

You need aggregation, but you need a definition of "most sold".  My guess is that this is based on quantity:

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.ProductName, SUM(od.ODProductQty) as TotalQty
FROM Products p INNER JOIN
     OrderDetails od
     ON p.ProductID = od.ODProductID INNER JOIN
     Orders o
     ON od.ODOrderID = o.OrderID 
WHERE Orders.OrderStatusID = 5
GROUP BY p.ProductID, p.ProductName
ORDER BY TotalQty DESC
LIMIT <n>;
```

Comment: @Webgen . . . Your question would suggest that the quantity is what you want:  "most sold product".

Comment: ur query was helpful my friend. Thanks a lot.